# Vim: Custom Folding function done, custom highlighting required

Tags: unix, vim, function, syntax-highlighting

I have defined a function in vim to properly indent folds.  Ie so they look like this:

#### Unfolded

```
this is text 
also text
    indented text
    indented text
not indented text
```

#### folded with default function

```
this is text 
also text
+-- 2 lines: indented text ----------------------------
not indented text
```

#### folded with my new function

```
this is text 
also text
    ++- 2 lines: indented text ----------------------------
not indented text
```

The only problem is the the highlighting is still like this:

#### folded with my new function (highlighting shown with  tag)

```
this is text 
also text
<hi>    ++- 2 lines: indented text ----------------------------</hi>
not indented text
```

I would like the highlighting to start at the ++ and not at the beginning of the line.  I have looked in the vim manual but could not find anything like that.  One so-so solution I found was to make the background black (same as my background).

```
highlight Folded ctermbg=black ctermfg=white cterm=bold
```

But this make folds less visible.

I have tried several variations of:

```
syn keyword Folded lines
syn region Folded ...
```

But I think that folds are selected differently and I cannot think of a way to override the default highlighting.  Can anyone offer a suggestion?

By the way this is my function to indent the folds:

```
set foldmethod=indent

function! MyFoldText()
        let lines = 1 + v:foldend - v:foldstart
        let ind = indent(v:foldstart)

        let spaces = ''
        let i = 0
        while i < ind
                let i = i+1
                let spaces = spaces . ' '
        endwhile

        let linestxt = 'lines'
        if lines == 1
                linestxt = 'line'
        endif

        return spaces . '+' . v:folddashes . ' '. lines . ' ' . linestxt . ': ' . getline(v:foldstaendfunction
endfunction


au BufWinEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile * set foldtext=MyFoldText()
```

By the way thanks to  [njd](https://superuser.com/questions/112497/vim-when-folding-code-allow-tabs-to-remain/112846#112846)  for helping me get this function setup.

*Note: I have cross posted this  [on super user](https://superuser.com/questions/118340/vim-custom-folding-function-done-custom-highlighting-required).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813060/syntax-highlighting-in-a-vim-fold-header) question
It seems that we cannot control the fold highlighting since it is not part of the file but formed and laid temporarily at folds.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the link.  That is what I suspected.  I am going to leave this question open for a few more days (hopefully someone has a trick).  But otherwise I will accept your answer.