# Change line nr color in folded line in vim

Tags: vim

line number for folded line has the same color as fold text and it differs from colors in other lines. Is there posibility to change line number color here?

Comment: To whoever voted to close as off topic, the FAQ explicitly allows questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers", which vim certainly qualifies as.

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax highlighting in a VIM fold header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813060/syntax-highlighting-in-a-vim-fold-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Folded line takes presedence because it is "made of"  several lines.