# Syntax-highlight Python in a vim fold line

Tags: python, vim, ide, syntax-highlighting, folding

I have found that [code-folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding) helps me organize my files better. Thus, at the bottom of my `~/.vimrc`, I enable [vim code folding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_28.html) by default:

```
""Folding
set foldmethod=indent
set foldnestmax=2
nnoremap <space> za
vnoremap <space> zf
"set nofoldenable       "set this to disable folding on file open
```

This has the advantages of using <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to toggle folds at the cursor, or if they start to annoy me I can use <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to unfold everything.

However, I'm also addicted to syntax highlighting.  I use Dmitry Vasiliev's [`python.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790), but it doesn't highlight syntax in a fold line:

[image: vim folded, no syntax highlighting]

The lack of syntax highlighting for `Field('id', type='integer', unique=True, notnull=True),` makes it hard on my eyes when I'm used to seeing the highlight colors

What I'm looking for is a `python.vim` that supports syntax highlighting on a fold summary... if it Dmitry's did, it would highlight the strings in green something like this:

[image: desired folding highlights]

I want to continue using `foldmethod=indent`, if possible.  Is there a way to get syntax highlights on fold summaries?  Perhaps another `python.vim`?

Comment: Great question. I have no idea if it's even possible, though.

Comment: I wouldn't like it ... folded lines are not only highlighted, but highlighted differently (in their own category) exactly for the reason to make them easier to distinguish. Highlighting them as any other would just blend them in more.

Comment: @ldigas Given that folded lines (on OP's picture) have different background color I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert - On the contrary, that is an additional difficulty. Because some of the syntax elements can blend in with the background, to which "they suppose" it is black.

Comment: @ldigas, I have no concerns about colored folds blending in more when folds are identified by a page-wide set of dashes, and I can jump through them with `zj`

Comment: Mike, just sayin'. In any case, I don't know whether what you are asking is possible.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert, the reason the lines in my picture have a grey background color is because I manually highlighted them in vim with shift-V for emphasis between the pictures.  The folds themselves are denoted by `+-- X lines: ... ------------------------------`

Comment: @MikePennington I see. /me not heavy _folder_. :) However if one is able to highlight parts of a fold it's quite likely he/she could manipulate its background color too—separately from the _normal_ background (in a way that there won't be blending).

Comment: @KohányiRóbert, correct. For instance, you can change the background highlighting of a fold with `:highlight Folded term=standout ctermfg=darkgrey ctermbg=white`. The aforementioned example would give folds a white background with grey lettering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1813060/1123582) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1813677/1123582) was that it's not possible since the fold headline is not actually part of the file, thus never gets scanned by the highlighter.  :(

Comment: I think we're choosing to interpret that differently.  I read it as him saying the *unindented* line would remain unfolded (wrapping the fold line proper) and could perhaps serve as a makeshift fold heading for you, not that the fold line itself would somehow have highlighted text embedded within it.